# How to install a specific .NET framework on an azure deployment slot?

Tags: azure, continuous-deployment

I've just updated a bunch of projects in a solution to .NET 7, the pipeline runs and builds but the release to a deployment slot fails claiming it doesn't have the .NET 7 SDK installed but the pipeline build says it's installed it.

What's going on here?

How do I install a .NET SDK on the deployment slot rather than just on the pipeline?

Pipeline build says it has installed .NET 7

```
Starting: Use .Net Core SDK
==============================================================================
Task         : Use .NET Core
Description  : Acquires a specific version of the .NET Core SDK from the internet or the local cache and adds it to the PATH. Use this task to change the version of .NET Core used in subsequent tasks. Additionally provides proxy support.
Version      : 2.222.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/AA4xgy0
==============================================================================
Tool to install: .NET Core sdk version 7.0.x.
Found version 7.0.304 in channel 7.0 for user specified version spec: 7.0.x
Version 7.0.304 was not found in cache.
Getting URL to download .NET Core sdk version: 7.0.304.
Detecting OS platform to find correct download package for the OS.
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& 'D:\a\_tasks\UseDotNet_b0ce7256-7898-45d3-9cb5-176b752bfea6\2.222.0\externals\get-os-platform.ps1'"
Primary:win-x64
Detected platform (Primary): win-x64
Downloading: https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/8f08bebf-8851-4cb3-9a16-7e800004867a/38369e796f1c61272732532e5b7c4fc3/dotnet-sdk-7.0.304-win-x64.zip
Extracting downloaded package D:\a\_temp\6a6cb175-3000-4602-94f0-e74469cbe0fa.
Extracting archive
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' ; try { Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem } catch { } ; [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('D:\a\_temp\6a6cb175-3000-4602-94f0-e74469cbe0fa', 'D:\a\_temp\87a4')"
Successfully installed .NET Core sdk version 7.0.304.
Creating global tool path and pre-pending to PATH.
Finishing: Use .Net Core SDK
```

But when deploying it says .NET 7 is missing.

```
2023-06-19T16:10:33.0095026Z ##[section]Starting: Run DbUp
2023-06-19T16:10:33.0199510Z ==============================================================================
2023-06-19T16:10:33.0199656Z Task         : PowerShell
2023-06-19T16:10:33.0199740Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
2023-06-19T16:10:33.0199837Z Version      : 2.220.0
2023-06-19T16:10:33.0199895Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-06-19T16:10:33.0199987Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
2023-06-19T16:10:33.0200094Z ==============================================================================
2023-06-19T16:10:34.0587880Z Generating script.
2023-06-19T16:10:34.1266651Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-06-19T16:10:34.1650120Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\a72656a1-821f-44b2-87b3-e5665e1db463.ps1'"
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4714677Z You must install or update .NET to run this application.
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4720104Z 
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4732166Z App: D:\a\r1\a\_Hstar\Hstar.Db\Hstar.Db.dll
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4734299Z Architecture: x64
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4735357Z Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '7.0.0' (x64)
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4735882Z .NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4736259Z 
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4766096Z The following frameworks were found:
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4768462Z   3.1.4 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4769808Z   3.1.6 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4771114Z   3.1.20 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4771530Z   3.1.32 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4771875Z   6.0.5 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4772236Z   6.0.16 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4772449Z 
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4772724Z Learn about framework resolution:
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4773036Z https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4773219Z 
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4773498Z To install missing framework, download:
2023-06-19T16:10:34.4773881Z https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=7.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
2023-06-19T16:10:34.7536691Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2023-06-19T16:10:34.7948758Z ##[section]Finishing: Run DbUp
```

[image: You must install or update .NET to run this application]

[image: .NET 7 installed]

Comment: Post text as *text*, not images. The first screen shows that only .NET 3 and 6 SDKs are installed, not 7. It's doesn't "claim", .NET 7 SDK isn't there

Comment: Build and deployment pipelines are different. In fact, *deployment* pipelines typically need only the runtime, not the SDK. Installing the SDK in  a build pipeline doesn't mean it's also installed (or needed) in the deployment pipeline.